# Writing a specific rows from csv file to another csv in Python

Tags: python, csv

I need Your help desperately because I'm getting a little obsessed with following case:

All, what I want to do is rewrite rows containing some specified string into another csv file.

I was trying various options found on StackOverflow, but none of these works in my case.

What I have till now:

```
import csv

with open("origin.csv") as file, open('results.csv','wb') as resultfile:
    originreader=csv.reader(file, delimiter=";')
    writer=csv.writer(resultfile)
    for row in originreader:
        if "Windows Server 2008 R2 for x64" in row:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

The origin file looks like:

```
Date;Product;Product Family;Platform;Article;Download;Details
04/12/2002;Windows Vista Service Pack 2;Windows;;3146963;Security Update;CVE-2016-0147
04/12/2002;Windows Server 2008 for 32-bit Systems Service Pack 2;Windows;;3146963;Security Update;CVE-2016-0147
04/12/2002;Windows Server 2008 R2 for x64-based Systems Service Pack 1;Windows;;3146963;Security Update;CVE-2016-0147
04/12/2002;Windows Server 2012 R2 (Server Core installation);Windows;;3146963;Security Update;CVE-2016-0147
04/12/2002;Windows 10 Version 1511 for 32-bit Systems;Windows;;3147458;Security Update;CVE-2016-0147
```

I hope I explained myself clearly. 
Please be lenient as I'm beginner and it is my first project running in Python.

Thanks in advance. 
Bartek

Comment: typo `csv.reader(file, delimiter=";')` => `csv.reader(file, delimiter=";")`

Comment: then `if "Windows Server 2008 R2 for x64" in row:` won't work because you're trying to check a substring in a list of strings. Make it `if "Windows Server 2008 R2 for x64" in row[1]:` since the relevant column seems to be the second one

Answer (score 0):

I would use pandas to do this task and a code like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('origin.csv', sep=";")
df_new = df[df['Product']=='Windows Server 2008 R2 for x64']
# or df_new = df[df['Product'].str.contains('Windows Server 2008 R2 for x64')]
df_new.to_csv('my_new.csv')
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open("origin.csv", "r") as file:
    originreader=csv.reader(file)
    header = next(originreader)
    found_data = []
    for row in originreader:
        new_data = dict(zip(header, row))
        if "Windows Server 2008 R2 for x64" in new_data.get("Product"):
            found_data.append(row)

with open('results.csv','w') as resultfile:
    write = csv.writer(resultfile)
    write.writerow(header)
    write.writerows(found_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
import csv

with open("origin.csv") as file, open('results.csv','w') as resultfile:
    originreader=csv.reader(file, delimiter=";")
    writer=csv.writer(resultfile)
    for row in originreader:
        if "Windows Server 2008 R2 for x64" in row[1]:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

- Fixed a typo in line 4 where you start with double quotation and try to close with single quotation
- In line 7 you were searching for a string in a list object. This will look only for *exact* matches. The new code scans only the second item in the list, a string and a string.